# How to get a GISAID account? I registered months ago, still no reply!

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, public-databases, sars-cov-2, variants

Inspired by [amateur variant hunters](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01047-4), I would like to join the Pango lineage proposal community and help contribute to variant surveillance.

However, I cannot seem to get access to GISAID, the platform that exclusively hosts a large share of SARS-CoV-2 sequences from around the world.

I applied/registered for an account back in summer 2022 (almost a year ago) using this form: https://gisaid.org/register/

But since then, nothing has happened. I have send an email and filled out the contact form on the website but never heard back.

I am very confused how GISAID can say they are a "public" database, while at the same time not giving accounts to people like me, not even responding to emails.

How does everyone else get access? Is there a secret email you need to contact? Or do you need to pay? I've read [here](https://www.science.org/content/article/invented-persona-behind-key-pandemic-database) which describes the founder of GISAID in detail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a GISAID account and it's subject to an approval process. It was pretty simple and is awarded quickly. There are definitely no fees needed. I personally didn't see the advantages over NCBI's really very impressive SARS-CoV-2 database system and thats what I'd recommend.

Their resource is here:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/virus/vssi/#/virus?SeqType_s=Nucleotide&VirusLineage_ss=SARS-CoV-2,%20taxid:2697049&ids=MZ039713%20MZ039682%20OV522182%20

Its perfect for interrogation, it has the full spectrum of epidemiological metadata, and further details are in this post here:

[How to programatically download SARS-CoV-2 fasta from NCBI/Genbank via API?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/how-to-programatically-download-sars-cov-2-fasta-from-ncbi-genbank-via-api/18643#18643)

The Science journal page seemed a very good write up of GISAID BTW.

---

If you are wanting GISAID for networking, thats a bit tricky because NCBI is not going to do that.
You can reapply for GISAID access, but at the time I was much more impressed by NCBI. The speed at which NCBI produced an awesome database was truly jaw-dropping and they'd implemented full pangolineages classification at an early stage. Thus I just use NCBI.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @gringer, much appreciated. ".. it has all the data" is good interpretation of what I wrote, but my writing wasn't clear. Specifically, "it has all the epidemiological metadata" is what I intended to say.